# TagBuilder not generating unqiue id attribute values across ajax requests

Tags: c#, ajax, razor

I have an issue where I'm using the same template to render some content on a page and the same template is used to render additional content on the page using an AJAX request.

The following code renders the partial razor view:

```
@model SearchBoxViewModel
<div class="smart-search">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 text-right">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SearchPhrase, new { @class = "control-label heading" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SearchPhrase, new {@class = "form-control", placeholder = "for products, companies, or therapy areas"})
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default"/>
            </div>
            <div class="what-to-search hidden-11 col-sm-11 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.WhatToSearch, null, false)
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.WhatToSearch)
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div> <!-- /.smart-search -->
```

The following code makes the AJAX request:

```
$.ajax(anchor.attr("data-overlay-url-action"))
        .done(function (data) {
            $("div.overlay").addClass("old-overlay");

            $("div.navbar").after(data);

            $("div.overlay:not(.old-overlay)")
                .attr("data-overlay-url-action", anchor.attr("data-overlay-url-action"))
                .hide()
                .fadeIn();

            $("div.old-overlay")
                .fadeOut()
                .removeClass("old-overlay");

            anchor.addClass("overlay-exists");
        });
```

So what you get is the same partial razor view output on the page twice, once during the page request and once during the AJAX request.

The problem is that TextBoxFor, CheckBoxFor, etc. all make use of TagBuilder.GenerateId to generate the id attribute value but it doesn't account for generating id's across multiple requests where AJAX might be involved. This results in the same id value being output on the page, causing JavaScript to break.

The following is the HTML that is output twice (once during the request and then added in a separate part of the page during an AJAX request):

```
<div class="smart-search">

<form role="form" method="get" class="form-horizontal" action="/PharmaDotnet/ux/WebReport/Search">        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 text-right">
                <label for="SearchPhrase" class="control-label heading">Search</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
                <input type="text" value="" placeholder="for products, companies, or therapy areas" name="SearchPhrase" id="SearchPhrase" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-1">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search">
            </div>
            <div class="what-to-search hidden-11 col-sm-11 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" value="true" name="WhatToSearch" id="WhatToSearch">
                        NewsManager Search Only
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form></div>
```

So the SearchPhrase and WhatToSearch id's are duplicated.

Is there any way to work around this, or is there a better way to render the form elements to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify your own ID for the items, and then you wouldn't have this ID collision problem. Have you tried setting the id manually: `Html.TextBoxFor( ... , new { id = "AnythingHere" })`, where the id could be a freshly generated Guid? (Note that you'd probably need to add a prefix, because Guids can start with a number.

So you can use the following. The Guid doesn't look good, and is unnecessarily long. You might want to go with something shorter, like short guid, `DateTime.Ticks`, ...

```
@{
  var id = "chk_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
@Html.CheckBoxFor(..., new { id = id })
@Html.LabelFor(..., new { @for = id })
```

Comment: I have something that takes the original id and appends a unique string to the end of it but I was hoping for something a bit more clever. The only problem with something a bit more clever is how will CheckBoxFor and DisplayNameFor know which two relate to each other so that the unique ID's match. I am even open to a different rendering engine that does this as I'm finding limitations with Razor all the time.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with specifying the ID yourself. I don't really see a limitation here. If you want a complex solution for this issue, you could try to identify each request uniquely, and based on that you could add a suffix to all elements. But to do this you'd need to write the helpers yourself.

Comment: The problem is more to do with keeping the code clean, and as this is going to be a common occurrence I'd rather not have to include what I consider to be a hack at the top of each partial razor view.

Comment: Then I don't see any other way than writing your own helper methods for the code generation. In AspNet.vNext there seems to be an `IHtmlGenerator` interface, which you can implement and probably register to the DI container to be picked up by the TagHelper. But I haven't tried.

Comment: I will look at porting over some code from ASP.NET 5 and see how I get on.